# How to correctly work with in app billing service in android?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am totally new in appbiling service in android, and it seems to be a little bit complicated for me, I have done all the initial procedures to implement it , but I am stuck in the purchase state(I think so).I have a list view and in the onitem click listener I have done this:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        purchaseposition= position;
        if(list.get(position).getPurchase().contentEquals("Buy")){
         val = billingService.requestPurchase("android.test.purchased", payloadContents);

        }else{
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
        editor.putInt("URLPOSITION", position);
        editor.commit();
        Intent quiz=new Intent("com.powergroupbd.appbil.QUIZACTIVITY");
        startActivity(quiz);
        }
    }
```

that means if the list view contains a text 'Buy' then I am sending request to the market to buy with the test purchase id.Now I want that if purchase is successfull then I will change the text of the list view from 'Buy' to 'Play' and enable the quiz to be played. But here is the part where I think I missed everthing. In the purchase state change I wrote this code to do this:

```
@Override
        public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState,
                String itemId, int quantity, long purchaseTime,
                String developerPayload) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.i("Tag", "onPurchaseStateChange() itemId: " + itemId + " "
                        + purchaseState);
            }

            if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                ownedItems.add(itemId);
                list.get(purchaseposition).setPurchase("Play");
            }
            // YOU can also add other checks here
        }
```

but it never change the text of the listview and I can never play the quiz, Please I need a complete Idea how can I do this and where is my mistake? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you displaying your data?

if you are using a listview and an array adapter, you need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` This tells the adapter you have updated information and it can refresh the list.  If your not using an array adapter, you could call `findViewById(int)` and dynamically change the view.